# How to add the full path with file to the view?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to send the full track to view and  display like http://localhost:8080/fileaName.  Then I push this link and  save file on  my disk.

```
           String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("src/main/resources/temp/")
            .path(fileName)
            .toUriString();
    model.addAttribute("fileDownloadUri", fileDownloadUri);
```

Now I can't see the link on the page

```
<span th:href="${fileDownloadUri}"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your controller's end point looks like. But I would use the below Controller and View to show a direct download link to a file.

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileId) {
        // Load file from your source
        AppUserDocument appUserDocument = someDocumentStorageService.getFile(fileId);


        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(appUserDocument.getFileType()))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + appUserDocument.getFileName() + "\"")
                .body(new ByteArrayResource(appUserDocument.getData()));
    }
```

And then on the thymeleaf view I would provide a download link like below:

```
<td> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" th:href="@{/downloadFile/{id}(id=${myfile.id})}">Download</a></td>
```

You can refer my github repo on above here:

https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootfileupldnldRESTDB

Or provide your full controller method reponsible for this. So that the SO folks can help you out.